# How to get text inside href?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to get the text inside an href link, in particular I've this:

```
<a href="/matches/2015/02/07/italy/serie-a/juventus-fc/ac-milan/1836527/" class="form-icon form-win " title="Juventus - Milan 3 - 1">W</a>
```

So I made this regex:

```
.giornata_1_casa_flag = Regex.Match(Casa_Rgx(0).Value, "/<a [^>]*href=""?([^"">]+)""?>/").Groups(2).ToString
```

the pattern, however, don't get any value. I'm waiting a result like: **W**.
This character allow me to execute many control.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: Are you sure regex is the right tool for the job here? Maybe an HTML *parser* would be a better tool.

Comment: What you want the output string to be? string within href or the value of a tag?

Comment: You can use regex here. A HTML parser is over the top for a simple job like this.

Comment: Yeah I know it, but it is only for learn. As I said in the main post, I want to get the text in the href tag, especially in this tag contains the letter w

Comment: @QuentinUK That's some *bad* advice.

Comment: @QuentinUK: well you even need to escape a href sometimes. For instance if one uses a space, it should be replaced with `%20`. So things are more complicated than one thinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to search for any text between `>` and `</a>`, probably not the best approach, but it depends on the html you have.

Here is the pattern: `(?<=>)[a-z\s]*(?=<\/a>)`

`(?<=>)` - positive lookbehind, means that before text should be `>` sign

`(?=<\/a>)` - positive lookahead, means that text should be followed by `</a>`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/iC9uR4/2

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery

```
var link = "<a href=''>Text link</a>"
var textLink = $(link).text();
```